# how to move single marker in google maps v2 android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I added a lot of markers in google maps v2 android, I use a hashtable to store the id of each marker, and the results I could make customwindow and so on, but the problem is I want to delete / move the marker based on the id.

This my code to create a marker, I parse data from json

```
private Hashtable<String, String> markers;
markers = new Hashtable<String, String>();

private void createMarker(String result) throws JSONException{

    jObject = new JSONObject(result);
    JSONArray menuitemArray = jObject.getJSONArray("data");
    for (int i = 0; i < menuitemArray.length(); i++) {
        id=menuitemArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id").trim();
        ttl=menuitemArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("user").trim();
        snip=menuitemArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("desc").trim();
        lat=menuitemArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("latitude").trim();
        lng=menuitemArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("longitude").trim();

        Marker mk = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat),Double.parseDouble(lng)))
        .title(ttl)
        .snippet(snipq)
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(BmFinal)));

        markers.put(mk.getId(), id); //here i add info to hastable marker

    }
}
```

I want to move marker in this void

```
private void moveMarker(String Id){
    //what should i do in here ???
}
```

how to I achieve that? thanks..

Comment: use,  marker.setPosition(latlng);

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment but you might want to try this; Remove the marker first then create another in the new place you want but with the same characteristics.
As example (Just so you get the idea):

```
public void moveMarker(String Id) {    

   markers.get(Id).remove(); // this removes the marker

   Marker newMk = googleMap.googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(newlat),Double.parseDouble(newlng))) // new coordonates
        .title(ttl)
        .snippet(snipq)
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(BmFinal))); // same details

        // now add to your map & collection
        markers.put(newMk.getId(), Id);
}
```

Comment: that bit of code should remove the desired marker from the map, because the Marker class supports a remove() method, [`Marker.remove()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html#remove()), but if you'd like to clear the whole map and redraw it, use: `GoogleMap.clear()` and if you just want to hide a single marker for later use this can help: [`Marker.setVisible(boolean)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html#setVisible(boolean))

Comment: yes,if marker class has a remove method,but I want to delete the marker is a marker that has the specified id and not removed through the selection of the marker so I had to check id first and then use the iteration to the rest of the marker and if the id exist then I delete