# how to calculate all of marker in google maps v2 android?

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

related to my previous question and unaswered in [how to move single marker in google maps v2 android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694538/how-to-move-single-marker-in-google-maps-v2-android) I have more question how to calculate(count) all of marker in google maps android v2?

I already one week looking for a solution to this problem but have not been able to answer, please help...

thanks

Comment: if your code to create marker is based on your unanswered question, then the number of marker would be the size of your `menuitemArray`

Comment: I think its the size of an array which you are inflating as a marker on the map.

Comment: Hi check this question link may it help on this.
[JS code to get count values from list then connect with hide/show select option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58097804/12117335)